# SQL split row based when column value is greater than 1 by date

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table that I need to split the columns on based one a date column and another column for values.

Essentially when there numbers column is greater than one, I need to split that column up on the same date until until that column equals one.

For example, this is the dataset that comes in

```
+----------------------------------------------+
|     CONF#   DATE       Numbers     Rev       |
+----------------------------------------------+
| ------- ----------- ----------- -----------  |
| 24720   01/10/2014  1           35           |
| 24437   11/09/2014  2           450          |
| 24007   04/08/2014  3           15           |
| 24628   25/09/2014  1           100          |
+----------------------------------------------+
```

The result I'm looking for

```
+----------------------------------------------+
|     CONF#   DATE        Numbers     Rev      |
+----------------------------------------------+
| ------- ----------- ----------- -----------  |
| 24720   01/10/2014  1           35           |
| 24437   11/09/2014  1           225          |
| 24437   11/10/2014  1           225          |
| 24007   04/08/2014  1           5            |
| 24007   04/09/2014  1           5            |
| 24007   04/10/2014  1           5            |
| 24628   25/09/2014  1           100          |
+----------------------------------------------+
```

The result set comes back with those rows greater than one broken up.
The rev is split evenly among the rows broken up.

I'm trying to write a cursor for this

```
    DECLARE cursor_SplitRow CURSOR
FOR SELECT 
      [Conf#]
FROM [table];

OPEN cursor_SplitRow;
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_SplitRow INTO 
@Conf#;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @counter INT = 1;
    WHILE @counter <= @Numbers
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO #TemptTable
            VALUES(@CONF#  ,
                   @DATE,
                   1,
                   @Rev/@numbers
```

I'm think that the code needs to run the to divide by how many it is past one, so if the number is 5, revenue has to be divided by 5 and split evenly, this is where I'm stuck

Answer (score 4):

Don't use a cursor.  Use a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select conf#, date, numbers, rev / numbers as rev, 1 as n
      from t
      union all
      select conf#, dateadd(day, 1, date), numbers, rev, n + 1
      from cte
      where n < numbers
     )
select conf#, date, 1 as n, rev
from cte;
```

If you have a numbers or tally table handy, you can use that as well:

```
with n as (
      select row_number() over (order by (select null)) as n
      from master..spt_values
     )
select t.conf#, dateadd(day, 1, t.date), 1 as number, t.rev / t.numbers
from t join
     n
     on n <= t.numbers;
```

Comment: @ConnorMeek . . . That is easy to incorporate into the query.

Comment: I deleted this last comment, I meant to say thank you.  the results are showing the rows correct.  The only thing now is the numbers where greater than 1 add, instead of being at 1.

Comment: Actually I got it from here, again thank you so, so much I really appreciate it

Answer (score 4):

You can also use an ad-hoc tally/numbers table

**Example**

```
Select [Conf#]
      ,[Date]
      ,[Numbers] = 1
      ,[Rev] = Rev/A.Numbers
 From YourTable A
 Join ( 
        Select Top 1000 N=Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) From master..spt_values n1, master..spt_values n2
      ) B on B.N<=A.Numbers
 Order By CONF# Desc
```

**Returns**

```
Conf#   Date        Numbers Rev
24720   01/10/2014  1       35.00
24628   25/09/2014  1       100.00
24437   11/09/2014  1       225.00
24437   11/09/2014  1       225.00
24007   04/08/2014  1       5.00
24007   04/08/2014  1       5.00
24007   04/08/2014  1       5.00
```